# Get the number of months between two DateTimes

Tags: vb.net

```
mnth = DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, 8/30/2012, 10/1/2012)
```

**gives** `mnth = 2`. But when we look, there is **only 32 days between these dates**. I am **expecting a result `mnth=1`** as **there is only 32 days between these days**.

***Pls help..***

In my scenario i can consider a 15+ days to be a month but if it is less than 15, it should'nt be considered.

Comment: Why? 32 days is 1 month plus an extra day. It's not going to just assume you don't care about that extra month.

Comment: wht should i do then?? i need to get the number of complete months here.. :(

Comment: What you should do is give a specification of what you expect your function to return which is not trivial. E.g. most people would agree that April 1 to May 1 or May 31 to June 30 both span an entire month. But what for April 30 to May 30 or April 15 to May 15?

Comment: @PaulB, you make a good point.

Comment: What is the definition of 'complete month'? 30 days or 31 days (not to mention 28/29 days)? It is a fixed constant or should change depending on the starting/Ending month?

Comment: You could calculate some day ratio, `date.Day / date.DaysInMonth`, to assess relative completion of the bounding months.

Comment: not an exact number of days.. a round off say 15+ days can be considered for a month. here there is only one or two days which is calculated as a month.

Comment: @Hybridzz, if you make a logical specification, it can be written. Edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the number of complete months you can do different things depending on your interpretation,

```
Public Function CompleteMonthsBetweenA( _
        ByVal start As DateTime, _
        ByVal end As DateTime) As Integer

    Dim invertor = 1

    If (start > end) Then
       Dim tmp = end
       end = start
       start = tmp
       invertor = -1
    End If

    Dim diff = ((end.Year - start.Year) * 12) + end.Month - start.Month

    If start.Day > end.Day Then
        Return (diff - 1) * invertor
    Else
        Return diff * invertor
    End If
End Function
```

With this function the number of complete months between 31/05/2011 (dd/mm/yy) and 30/06/2011 is 0 but between 30/06/2011 and 31/07/2011 is 1. Which may or may not be what you expect.

---

```
Public Function CompleteMonthsBetweenB( _
        ByVal start As DateTime, _
        ByVal end As DateTime) As Integer

    Dim invertor = 1

    If (start > end) Then
       Dim tmp = end
       end = start
       start = tmp
       invertor = -1
    End If

    Dim diff = ((end.Year - start.Year) * 12) + end.Month - start.Month

    Dim startDaysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(start.Year, start.Month)
    Dim endDaysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(end.Year, end.Month)

    If (start.Day / startDaysInMonth) > (end.Day / endDaysInMonth) Then
        Return (diff - 1) * invertor
    Else
        Return diff * invertor
    End If
End Function
```

With this function the ratio `Day / DaysInMonth` is taken so the relative completion of the two months can be assessed.

---

```
Public Function CompleteMonthsBetweenC( _
     ByVal start As DateTime, _
     ByVal enddate As DateTime) As Integer

    Dim invertor = 1

    If (start > enddate) Then
        Dim tmp = enddate
        enddate = start
        start = tmp
        invertor = -1
    End If

    Dim diff = ((enddate.Year - start.Year) * 12) + enddate.Month - start.Month

    Dim remainingDays = _
      (DateTime.DaysInMonth(start.Year, start.Month) - start.Day) + enddate.Day

    If remainingDays < 15 Then
        Return (diff - 1) * invertor
    Else
        Return diff * invertor
    End If
End Function
```

This function only rounds down if the surplus days are less than the magic number 15, which I think is what you are asking for in your update.

---

```
Public Function CompleteMonthsBetweenD( _
        ByVal start As DateTime, _
        ByVal end As DateTime) As Integer

    Return end.Subtract(start).TotalDays \ 30.436875
End Function
```

This function takes the simpler approach of dividing the total number of days by the average number of days per month in the Gregorian Calendar.

Comment: @Hybridzz, that should do it.

Comment: @Hybridzz, it does of course depend on what you are expecting.

Comment: ok.. for me i can take a 15+ days to be a month. I surely appreciate ur effort.

Comment: The null checks don't add much value. `DateTime` is a value type, it cannot be null.

Comment: @Hybridzz, so did you get your answer?

Comment: i 've chose ur 'C' function with a bit modification. Lemme try this. :) THANKZ

Comment: @Hybridzz, I got the DaysInMonth call wrong but I've made it more readable now.

Answer (score 2):

The difference in months is calculated without regard to the day component of the dates.

For example, the difference in months between `8/31/2012` and `9/1/2012` is 1, eventhough it's only one day between the dates.

If you want to consider the day component you have to get the date difference in days instead of months, and calculate how many months you want that to be.

Comment: oh ok.. :( so can u give an exact solution that can be applied..??

Answer (score 1):

This is the class I use (it's C# but really easy to convert to VB.NET).
It is usefull for years, months, days... it is ideal for displaying ages in #Y-#M-#D format.

```
public class DateDifference
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// defining Number of days in month; index 0=> january and 11=> December
        /// february contain either 28 or 29 days, that's why here value is -1
        /// which wil be calculate later.
        /// </summary>
        private int[] monthDay = new int[12] { 31, -1, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

    /// <summary>
    /// contain from date
    /// </summary>
    private DateTime fromDate;

    /// <summary>
    /// contain To Date
    /// </summary>
    private DateTime toDate;

    /// <summary>
    /// this three variable for output representation..
    /// </summary>
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    public DateDifference(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
    {
        int increment;

        if (d1 > d2)
        {
            this.fromDate = d2;
            this.toDate = d1;
        }
        else
        {
            this.fromDate = d1;
            this.toDate = d2;
        }
        /// 
        /// Day Calculation
        /// 
        increment = 0;

        if (this.fromDate.Day > this.toDate.Day)
        {
            increment = this.monthDay[this.fromDate.Month - 1];

        }
        /// if it is february month
        /// if it's to day is less then from day
        if (increment == -1)
        {
            if (DateTime.IsLeapYear(this.fromDate.Year))
            {
                // leap year february contain 29 days
                increment = 29;
            }
            else
            {
                increment = 28;
            }
        }
        if (increment != 0)
        {
            day = (this.toDate.Day + increment) - this.fromDate.Day;
            increment = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            day = this.toDate.Day - this.fromDate.Day;
        }

        ///
        ///month calculation
        ///
        if ((this.fromDate.Month + increment) > this.toDate.Month)
        {
            this.month = (this.toDate.Month + 12) - (this.fromDate.Month + increment);
            increment = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            this.month = (this.toDate.Month) - (this.fromDate.Month + increment);
            increment = 0;
        }

        ///
        /// year calculation
        ///
        this.year = this.toDate.Year - (this.fromDate.Year + increment);

    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        //return base.ToString();
        return this.year + " Year(s), " + this.month + " month(s), " + this.day + " day(s)";
    }

    public int Years
    {
        get
        {
            return this.year;
        }
    }

    public int Months
    {
        get
        {
            return this.month;
        }
    }

    public int Days
    {
        get
        {
            return this.day;
        }
    }
}
```

**USAGE:**

```
DateDifference diff = new DateDifference(date1, date2);
int months = (diff.Years*12) + diff.Months + diff.Days > 15 ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: This doesen't actually answer the question, just tries to recreate the functionality that is present in `DateTime.DaysInMonth`

Comment: @Jodrell, it really answer the question... but I agree with you that some parts of the code could use the DayInMonths. Use it and compare results with other methods.

Comment: Well, it is an overkill to the question... it is more helpful in more accurate scenaries.

Comment: `strAge` isn't a number of whole months. You could argue it is a more sensible answer than a bare number but `TimeSpan` is better still.

Comment: There you have a more explicit usage... I think it answer what user wanted. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of complete month, then you'll need to compare date that starts at the begining of the closet month.

```
Sub Main()

    ' mnth = DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, 8/30/2012, 10/1/2012)  

    Console.WriteLine(GetCompleteMonthCount(New DateTime(2012, 8, 30), New DateTime(2012, 10, 1)))
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub


Public Function GetCompleteMonthCount(ByVal d1 As DateTime, ByVal d2 As DateTime) As Integer

    If d1.Day <> 1 Then
        d1 = d1.AddMonths(1)
        d1 = New DateTime(d1.Year, d1.Month, 1)
    End If

    If d2.Day <> 1 Then
        d2 = New DateTime(d2.Year, d2.Month, 1)
    End If

    Return DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, d1, d2)
End Function
```

Comment: Is 01/01/1970 to 31/01/1970 a complete month? It all rather depends on your expectation.

Answer (score -1):

The solutions above are all very good but perhaps a little over-complicated, how about

```
Function wholeMonthsEd(d1, d2) As Integer

    ' determine the DateDiff function output
    ' which gives calendar month difference
    initMonths = DateDiff("m", d1, d2)

    ' do calcs on the Day of the month to deduct/not a calendar month
    If Day(d2) < Day(d1) Then
        initMonths = initMonths - 1
    End If

    wholeMonths = initMonths

End Function
```

Comment: This doesnt work well, please check https://dotnetfiddle.net/5vFprF